# iOS storyboard: set a background color to prototype cell

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, prototype, xcode4.5

I am facing a very strange issue with XCode 4.5.

I tried to set a background color to a prototype cell in my storyboard, but in interface builder the cell color doesn't change, even when I run it on my device it doesn't use the color I set.

I tried creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and setting the color of the background in all init methods but it still donnot work.

PS: XCode 4.5.1 and iOS 5 or 6, same issue. Since I'm a new developer I cannot recall if it worked on previous versions of XCode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to add a background color to a prototype UITableViewCell inside of a storyboard in Xcode 5.

First, select the cell that you want to give a background color.

Next, goto View -> Utilities -> Identity Inspector and add a new User Defined Runtime Attribute for a Keypath of "backgroundColor" a type of "Color" and a "Value" of whatever color you want.

[image: Screenshot of Identity Inspector panel]

Answer (score 6):

@dvkch: I don't know how you did it with deleting and recreating segues. The only way I know to set the background color of table view cell is to set the content views background color of the cell:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Sadly, storyboard doesn't show the content views properties.

---

EDIT

If you change the background color of the table view the background color of the cell changes, too.

Comment: The contentView can be selected in xcode 5 (don't know about previous versions) by clicking the prototype cell, but no the views in it. Iterating through the view with TAB / SHIFT+TAB can help

Answer (score -1):

It finally worked after some Clean and Clean build folder operations, some deletion of segues and after recreated them... Thanks Xcode 4.5 !

EDIT: after multiple tests: on iOS6 and 7 you actualy should be able to set the correct background color in storyboards or your code by setting the background color on the cell prototype itself and the contentView. Those are not the same objects in a storyboard. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm interested to see how you got this to work. You need to set the backgroundColor property of the cells contentView, and storyboards doesn't seem to expose these properties. Can you detail your solution?

Comment: indeed this didn't work, but problem solved after some cleanups, unfortunately I donnot know precisely what I did.

Comment: after some research, setting the background of a cell still donnot work on XCode 4.5.2, but I managed to change the background of the cell by setting the background of the whole UITableView

Comment: I think this shouldn't be marked as correct, as this isn't an answer nor leads to one...

Comment: You should select one of the others as the answer.

Comment: To me this is still the correct answer since it was a bug in this particular Xcode version and the question was clearly how to work around it. But since the post may appear in other circumstances I selected another one as correct, though it's now outdated since Xcode 6, or at least can be done in an easier way