# Prototype in Interface Builder ≠ Runtime Result for UITableView header cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

There seems to be a problem with prototyping a Table View Cell Header in iOS 8.3 / XCode 6.3 using Swift 1.2. The background color is not transferred from the prototype.

This is what I prototyped:

[image: Interface Builder prototypes]

(Screenshot from Interface Builder)

but this is what I get at runtime:

[image: Runtime result]

I solved the problem by adding the *this line was the fix* line:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyHeader") as! MyHeaderTVCell
    headerCell.HeaderCaption.text = tmpSectionHeaders[section];
    headerCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor() // this line was the fix

    return headerCell
}
```

So this code works fine... but that goes against the principle of a Prototype doesn't it?!! I don't want to set the background at runtime, just the content (Text and / or settings) of the Prototype instance copy.

There is a somewhat related topic on this that I found: [iOS storyboard: set a background color to prototype cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861289/ios-storyboard-set-a-background-color-to-prototype-cell) but there still is quite a difference.

N.b. when I use the sourcecode from above I do get the desired result b.t.w. but I don't like setting the background (again) in the  *headerCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()* line. Any ideas and/or solutions on this?

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer, not as an edit to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have pinpointed the problem a bit more. It seems that if I use a clear background in IB these symptoms happen. When I select groupTableViewBackgroundColor as the background color it works without the need to set the color. So it is more an IB problem (not wysiwyg) than a code problem.

N.b. Thanks KPM for the feedback on how to post it!